# Visual Studio macOS XAML Cache

Tags: macos, visual-studio, xaml, xamarin.forms

I have a Xamarin.Forms project that I work on in Windows for the Windows version and macOS for the iOS version.

If I edit a .xaml file on Windows, check it in through git, then check it out with git on the Mac, then Visual Studio shows the XAML as being what I last edited on the Mac instead of what I just pull down from git.

Using Atom, I can see that the XAML has the correct content.  Using Visual Studio **on macOS**, it shows some cached version.

I've deleted the obj, bin and ~/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs

Comment: Hi, do you mean that the VS for Mac shows some cached version?

Comment: I thought that was clear... but to be redundant, I added  **on macOS**

Comment: Okey, what's the version of vs for Mac , whether be the latest ? I will check that.

Comment: I'm always using the latest version.  It's been happening for at least a year though, so it's been happening for several versions now.  The question is, where is the cache?  It doesn't change every version... where's the cache?